# QML and JSON: access to a field specified in a variable

Tags: javascript, json, qt, qml

I need to access to a Json string inside my qml code, now if the field is known is is easy.

Given {"c1":320, "c2":256, "c3":128}

I can

```
function getC1(jsonstr)
{
   const obj = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
   return obj.c1;
}
```

But what if I don't know in advance which field to access and have it in a variable.

like obj["c1"] or obj[variable] syntaxes are not working. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with your assertion that those other methods you tried don't work. Here is what I did:

```
    property string json: '{"c1":320, "c2":256, "c3":128}'

    function getC1(jsonstr)
    {
        const obj = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
        const key = "c1";
        console.log(obj.c1);
        console.log(obj["c1"]);
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        getC1(json);
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
qml: 320
qml: 320
qml: 320
```

So all 3 methods produce the desired output.